# How to make a glib app look for "schema" at a different path?

Tags: glib

I've built and installed a Glib-2.0-using application to `/opt/myapp`.  However, when I run it, it looks for "schema" files under `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`.

How can I tell the app to look for schema files elsewhere?

Notes:

- A runtime solution would be preferable to a compile-time solution.
- It's nemo 4.8.6, built using meson.
- The distribution is Devuan GNU/Linux Beowulf.

Answer (score 1):

There's an environment variable controlling where Glib searches for "settings schemas": `GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR`. So, execute:

```
export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR="/opt/myapp/share/glib-2.0/schemas:${GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR}"
```

(assuming that's where your app's schema files are).

A more 'blunt' alternative, but which may resolve some other issues, is adding a path to the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variables; those paths are used, in particular, as roots for searching for schemas. So:

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/opt/myapp/share/:${XDG_DATA_DIRS}"
```

Thanks goes to @steeldriver for their comment.